# Embedded Resources and ASPX pages

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, web-parts, embedded-resource

Is it possible to embed an aspx page (self contained, no seperate codebehind file) into an assembly, in this case a SharePoint web part, and have it still act as an aspx file when called via the resource url?

Regards
Moo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no as such. however you can change you web part to a user control and enbed that in a webpart and a a aspx file.

Google for "user Control Web Part"

OR

you can look at "son of smartpart" but I don't like this approach. not very pure.

OR

Leave it as a aspx page and use the page viewer web part to load the aspx page in an iframe from sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

Download the Web Deployment Project update from MS, and it will solve your problem.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=0AA30AE8-C73B-4BDD-BB1B-FE697256C459&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [httphandler](http://codebetter.com/blogs/karlseguin/archive/2006/05/24/145397.aspx) but then you would have to make changes to web.config. What is your real problem? You can easily deploy a separate ASPX page when you use something like [WSPBuilder](http://www.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?ProjectName=wspbuilder) to create your SharePoint code.

Comment: The original goal was to avoid using a wsp for this specific instance, and at the same time avoid having multiple files needing to be copied to different places in the SharePoint site hierarchy.  In the end we bit the bullet and used wspbuilder to generate the wsp.